# HTML , resize div height with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resizing() {
var h = screen.height;
var dh = h - 270;
document.getElementById('chat').style.height = dh;
}
</script>

<body onload="resizing();">
<div id='chat' style='position: fixed;left: 0px;top: 45px;width: 80%;border-radius: 8px;border: 1px solid #000;'>HI</div>
</body>
```

not working , not resizing div :( how to resize div height javascript ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add units `px` to the number:

```
document.getElementById('chat').style.height = dh + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('chat').style.height= dh + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

These properties may not work in Firefox, Chrome, and other non-IE browsers. To make this work in all browsers, I suggest you to try the following:

```
document.getElementById('chat').setAttribute("style","height:" + dh + 'px');
```